# Export in standalone app not working while functionning in Eclipse

Tags: java, deployment

I'm working on a standalone app where results are exported in an excel sheet. I use Jxls for the export. All is working in Eclipse, but the exported jar just gives me a non-working sheet. Is it a problem with the output stream that doesn't write anything, or is it something with the absolute path? I'm a bit confused here.

The export is made with the required libraries packed in the jar.

The code of the exporting part :

```
    private void exportDataDet(File file) throws ParseException, IOException, ParsePropertyException, InvalidFormatException {

String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "tempFile";
File IdGenreXLS = new File(path + ".xlsx");
List<ResultsDetails> detRes = generateResultsDetails();

    try(InputStream is = IdGenre.class.getResourceAsStream("/xlsTemplates/IdGenre/IdGenre_20-29-et=12.xlsx")) {
            try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(IdGenreXLS)) {
                Context context = new Context();
                context.putVar("detRes", detRes);
                JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(is, os, context);
            }
        }
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the hypothesis that nothing was written on disk was the good one, as eventually nothing was written on disk.
A simple

```
os.flush();
```

at the end makes everything working. There's nothing for it but to close the input and output stream after.